# Ubuntu 18.04 -- Unattended Upgrade Fails with 404 Not Found

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

Why does Unattended Upgrade on Ubuntu 18.04 give 404 Not Found?

I get 404 Not Found during Unattended Upgrade.

This is the package: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-gcp/linux-gcp_5.0.0.1020.25_amd64.deb

Then I run wget manually and same problem:

wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-gcp/linux-gcp_5.0.0.1020.25_amd64.deb

Gives:

```
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-gcp/linux-gcp_5.0.0.1020.25_amd64.deb

Resolving security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.88.24, 91.189.88.149, 91.189.88.173, ...
Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.24|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: UPDATE 1: after running apt-get update, sudo unattended-upgrade runs OK. But this is hardly UNATTENDED. Do I have to script apt-get update? That would suck.